# How to recover this file in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse I had made several changes to a file. Then when I opened the file again I couldn't see the changes. I guess I forgot to save it. Not only that, but I removed the project. Is there a way to get my changes back?

Answer (score 1):

if you havent deleted the project from the disk just from eclipse then you can import again your project. Then each file has a local history that is auto saved. You can right click on the file and compare to local history

Comment: How? I right-clicked, selected Replace With->Local History... It just said No local history available for selected resource.

Comment: that means no luck for you, eclipse didnt save anything